# How to add automatic click feature in chrome extension?

Tags: click, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension, and need to click on the first link automatically for some time. 
Is it possible to add automatic click feature in chrome extension??

Comment: Is clicking a link different from getting link's url and forwarding a browser there? If not then which part do you have trouble with?

Comment: @serg: Yes, because sometimes links will have onclick handlers, and you may want to trigger them, for various reasons. This is especially true for "AJAX-y" apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about mouse coordinates, you can use this:

```
var trigger = document.createEvent("Event");
trigger.initEvent("click", true, true);
element.dispatchEvent(trigger);
```

"element" should be the DOM node you want to trigger the click on. If you want to also specify a particular X/Y coordinate, you could use this:

```
var x = 0,
    y = 0;

var trigger = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
trigger.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, null, 0, x, y, x, y, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
element.dispatchEvent(trigger);
```

Change `x` and `y` to what you want ...or just use jQuery, like npdoty said.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a nice `trigger` function for just such a situation ([jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)), even a shortened form just for the `click` event, and that pairs nicely with the `:first` pseudo-selector.

```
$('a:first').click();
```

You can probably do this in pure JavaScript as well, using some combination of `element.click()` or [dispatching events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent).